# I'm trying to create a pathway grid that has holes using Pascal's triangle in latex. Also the compass

Tags: tikz-pgf, grids

The picture below gives the idea of what I'm trying to do.

Also I'm not sure which tag to use for this specific question.

[image: New Picture]

> The code I am using:

```
 \documentclass[28pt]{article}

 \usepackage{fancyhdr}

 \usepackage[includeheadfoot,margin=1.0cm]{geometry} 
 \usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
 \usepackage{enumitem}
 \usepackage{mathtools}
 \usepackage{framed}
 \usepackage{chessfss} %chess figure for HW #2
 \usepackage[english]{babel} %table for problem A.43
 \usepackage{multirow} %table for problem A.43
%\usepackage[table]{xcolor} color certain blocks in a table
%\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}  just to show the margins
 \usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}
 \usepackage{array}  %BETWEEN TWO 2-DIGIT NUMBERS

 \newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
 \newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
 \newcommand{\thedate}{\today}

 \newtheoremstyle{case}{}{}{}{}{}{:}{ }{}
 \theoremstyle{case}
 \newtheorem{case}{Case}


 \newenvironment{theorem}[2][Theorem]{\begin{trivlist}
 \item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #2.}]}{\end{trivlist}}
 \newenvironment{lemma}[2][Lemma]{\begin{trivlist}
 \item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #2.}]}{\end{trivlist}}
 \newenvironment{exercise}[2][Exercise]{\begin{trivlist}
 \item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #2.}]}{\end{trivlist}}
 \newenvironment{problem}[2][Problem]{\begin{trivlist}
 \item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #2.}]}{\end{trivlist}}
 \newenvironment{question}[2][Question]{\begin{trivlist}
 \item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #2.}]}{\end{trivlist}}
 \newenvironment{corollary}[2][Corollary]{\begin{trivlist}
 \item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #2.}]}{\end{trivlist}}

 \begin{document}

 \end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: @TonioElGringo I am new to latex. The information that I DO know does not extend to graphics like this. I can create a basic table, but nothing on this scale. I have seen an example of a hole grid online, but the code was not available. I thought I could ask someone on this site to help. I guess not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this does it:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=2cm,y=-2cm, node 0/.style={fill=red!20}]
\tikzmath{%
  int \i, \j, \m, \n, \t;
  \m = 6; \n = 6;
  % Initialise board.
  for \i in {0,...,\m}{
    for \j in {0,...,\n}{
      \t{\i,\j} = 0;
    };
  };
  % Create holes.
  \t{0,3} = -1;
  \t{4,4} = -1;
  \t{5,1} = -1;
  \t{2,5} = -1;
  % Perform calculations.
  for \i1 in {0,...,\m}{
    for \j1 in {0,...,\n}{
      if (\t{\i1,\j1} == -1) then {
          \t{\i1,\j1} = 0;
      } else {
        if (\i1 == 0 || \j1 == 0) then  {
          \t{\i1,\j1} = 1;            
        } else {
          \i2 = \i1 - 1;
          \j2 = \j1 - 1;
          \t{\i1,\j1} = \t{\i2,\j1} + \t{\i1,\j2}; 
        };
      };
    };
  };
  % Draw nodes.
  for \i1 in {0,...,\m}{
    for \j1 in {0,...,\n}{
    { \node [circle, fill=blue!20, minimum size=1cm, node \t{\i1,\j1}/.try] 
        (n-\i1-\j1) at (\j1, \i1) {\t{\i1,\j1}}; };
    };   
  };
  % Draw edges.
  for \i1 in {0,...,\m}{
    for \j1 in {0,...,\n}{
      \i2 = \i1 + 1;
      \j2 = \j1 + 1;
      if (\i1 < \m) then {
        if (\t{\i2,\j1} > 0) then { 
              { \draw [thick, -stealth] (n-\i1-\j1) -- (n-\i2-\j1); };
          }; 
        };
        if (\j1 < \n) then {
        if (\t{\i1,\j2} > 0) then { 
              { \draw [thick, -stealth] (n-\i1-\j1) -- (n-\i1-\j2); };
        }; 
      };
    };
  };
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Without 'holes' it can be done much more simply:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usepackage{xintexpr}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=2cm,y=2cm]
\draw [help lines] grid [step=1] (6,-6);
\foreach \x in {0,...,6}
  \foreach \y in {0,...,6}
    \node [circle, fill=blue!20, minimum size=1cm]
      at (\x, -\y) {\xinttheiiexpr binomial(\x+\y,\x)\relax};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So the lines that are squiggled out are technically the "holes" in the grid. How should I go about creating that too. i.e where 4 and 6 meet to make 10 the line from 6 to 10 doesn't exist. I will use the grid and the code above to show a before and after picture.

Comment: I see that in your code \documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone} is perfect if you just wanted it be alone. If I got rid of the "standalone" and used article and plugged in your code into my code, will it be ok?

Comment: @Nixie777 you would need to add `\usepackage{tikz}` to the preamble.